# Windows 8 Install - USB

Tags: installation, dual-boot, usb, startup

I am trying to create a bootable USB to install Windows 8 using Ubuntu 13.04. I tried using WinUSB but it was showing an error saying that the USB is set to readable, which is weird since WinUSB was the program that formatted it. Not sure what to do with that but I am open to other ideas and other software. Any ideas on what to do next? Would Unetbootin work?

Comment: user186767, how did you fix the freezing part?

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that you have Gparted, and Ntfs-3g installed, and P7zip.

If not, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
sudo apt-get install p7zip-full
```

Once the installation is done, download and install [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/unetbootin-linux-latest) for Linux.  For all the steps, follow the images below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

You run UNetbootin, by double clicking on it, but before you run it, right click on the file, and follow steps outlined by the images below.

[image]

[image]

Make sure that you have the Windows ISO available, and follow the steps outlined in the image below.

[image]

Once done, make sure that your system is set to boot from USB, insert the USB to boot from it, and reboot your machine.

Comment: But my drive is unmounted, it won't show up as a drive at all for Unetbootin or anything for that matter.

Comment: I did these commands.

mkdir /media/drive
mount /dev/sdg1 /media/drive

And it is now properly mounted and useable but it doesn't show up in unetbootin. I've had this issue in the past.

Comment: What happens when you just remove the USB, and insert it, does is show up in file manager?

Comment: It doesn't do an action. But it shows up with the icon whether it is mounted or not. If I mount it, then I can store stuff on it. But I can only store stuff if it is Ntfs due to the fact that it doesn't have permission.

Comment: Alright, I formatted the device to fat32, manually mounted it to /media/drive and it shows up on Unetbootin. I selected the ISO and everything correctly, clicked OK and it froze at 26%.

Comment: unetbootin is a package, installable by `apt-get install unetbootin`

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to fix the freezing part. It now is officially extracted to the USB using UNetbootin. When I restart the computer and startup with the USB it shows a title saying UNetbootin and a box for choices of startup. I then choose Default because that's the only choice. It also says: `Automatic boot in 10 seconds...` and counts down. I click Enter on Default and it restarts the timer. When the timer gets to 0 it restarts. Any idea? Also the USB doesn't mount itself. I have to manually mount it every time it's unplugged or I restart my PC.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a blank USB drive (this will wipe out anything that may be on it) you can simply do:

```
sudo dd if=/path/to/windows_install.iso of=/dev/sdX bs=4M; sync
```

Where you need to replace the X /dev/sdX with the identifier of your USB stick, this will be a letter such as a, b, c, d, etc. It will *not* have a number on it, if you have an identifier such as /dev/sdc1, that means there is a partition (possibly with data on it) on that device that will be destroyed with the above command.